# Two pdf standalone pictures side by side in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, standalone

This is what I have done so far. I have used minipage here but beforehand I tried columns and the outcome was exactly the same.
What am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{frame}{Pratice Questions}
\begin{minipage}{0.5 \textwidth}
    \includestandalone[width=.5\textwidth,]{prop2}
    \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5 \textwidth}
\includestandalone[width=.5\textwidth,]{prop1}
\end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
```

[image]

```
\begin{frame}{Practice Questions}
%\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.48 \textwidth}
    \centering
    \includestandalone[width=\linewidth,]{prop2}
    \caption{hmmmmm}
\end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.48 \textwidth}
    \centering
    \includestandalone[width=\linewidth,]{prop1}
    \caption{hmmmm1}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use 0.5\textwidth as the width, there is a space between the minipages so the total width is `\textwidth` plus one space which is wider than the line. try `0.49\textwidth` on the minipages and use `width=\linewidth` on the images, then it will adapt it self to the width of the minipage.

Comment: Thanks! linewidths was helpful.  I have changed my code slightly since.  Ideally, I want two tikz standalone pictures side by side with captions.

Comment: Update your equation, comments are not build for large amounts of code

Comment: Question, not equation

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't leave a line break between `\end{minipage}` and `\begin{minipage}`, so try adding `%` right after `\end{minipage}`.

Anyway I suggest using `columns`, like this:

```
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{prop2}

\column{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{prop1}
\end{columns}
```

---

Following the comment, if you want to add a caption you can use the command `\captionof{figure}{Your caption.}` right after your figure inclusion. You need to load the `caption` package.

Comment: from second OP'+s code example follows, that (s)he like to have captions below images..